# React Native: filtered array failed to pass value to usestates

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

In my project, I had retrieved a list of arrays from firestore database in UseEffect(). After that, I had filtered the list of arrays into a single array called medicineStock and passing each value to new React useStates (editMedicineName, editMedicineRegNo, and editMedicineType) and making them as values in my input, however it doesn't pass anything into each useStates and my input field stays empty.

```
function EditMedicine() {

  const { medicineId } = useParams();

  const [medicine, setMedicine] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'medicine'), where("isAccepted", "==", true) )
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      setMedicine(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        data: doc.data()
      })))
    })
  },[])

  const medicineStock = medicine.filter(medicineStock => medicineStock.id === medicineId);

  const [editMedicineName, setEditMedicineName] = useState(medicineStock.map(item => item.data.medicineName).toString());
  const [editMedicineRegNo, setEditMedicineRegNo] = useState(medicineStock.map(item => item.data.medicineRegNo).toString());
  const [editMedicineType, setEditMedicineType] = useState(medicineStock.map(item => item.data.medicineType).toString());


  return (
    <div className='editMedicine'>
      <div className="editMedicine-title">Edit Medicine</div>
      <form className="editMedicine-form" >
          <div>
            <p>
              <label className="editMedicine-dataTitle">Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
              <input 
                name="medicineName" 
                type="text" 
                required
                className="editMedicine-input" 
                value={editMedicineName}
                onChange={(e) => setEditMedicineName(e.target.value)}
              />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label className="editMedicine-dataTitle">Reg No:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
              <input 
                name="medicineRegNo" 
                type="text" 
                required
                className="editMedicine-input" 
                value={editMedicineRegNo}
                onChange={(e) => setEditMedicineRegNo(e.target.value)}
              />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label className="editMedicine-dataTitle">Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
              <select className="editMedicine-input" value={editMedicineType} onChange={(e) => setEditMedicineType(e.target.value)}>
                <option value="Tablet">Tablet</option>
                <option value="Capsule">Capsule</option>
                <option value="Liquid">Liquid</option>
                <option value="Spray">Spray</option>
                <option value="Cream">Cream</option>
                <option value="Ointment">Ointment</option>
              </select>
            </p>
          </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tired to console.log the medicineStock which contain the filtered single array in the medicine object and console return this:

```
[]
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

[{…}]
0:
data:
donationId: "XOCXD3FFaWGjO3oZcJmc"
medicineName: "Fluticasone Nasal Spray BP 50 mcg"
medicineRegNo: "MAL14125126AZ"
medicineType: "Spray"
[[Prototype]]: Object
id: "Ko6KqA9nyIotUVOkmfPL"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Where the first console.log return no value, while second console.log return the value I want to put into the React usestates. Is there any solution to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is few misunderstoods about how useState works in your code and generally how you can trigger a rerendering.

**What is happening in your code:**

1. You init `medicine` state property with an empty array -> OK
2. You declare a new constant `medicineStock` which is a filtered version of `medicine`. At this moment `medicineStock` is an empty array too.
3. You init 3 new states properties with an initialValue based on medicineStock. It will produce 3 new empty strings. Here you have to understand that the initialValue of a state is not designed to update it but only to init it. If you update medicineStock, it will not update `editMedicineName` for example.
4. Then you fetch some data and call `setMedicine` to store it. This will have for effect to trigger a new rendering. So the body of your function will be read again. Of course `medicineStock` will have a new value a this moment and that's why you are able to see it with your log. But as I said before, this will not update `editMedicineName`, `editMedicineRegNo` and `editMedicineType`. The only way to update these values is to call their owns setters.

**How to fix it:**

I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve here but a simple fix for your code would be:

```
  const [editMedicineName, setEditMedicineName] = useState();
  const [editMedicineRegNo, setEditMedicineRegNo] = useState();
  const [editMedicineType, setEditMedicineType] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'medicine'), where("isAccepted", "==", true) )
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      const medecine = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        id: doc.id,
        data: doc.data()
      }));

      const medicineStock = medicine.filter(medicineStock => medicineStock.id === medicineId);

      setEditMedicineName(medicineStock.map(item => item.data.medicineName).toString());
      setEditMedicineRegNo(medicineStock.map(item => item.data.medicineRegNo).toString());
      setEditMedicineType(medicineStock.map(item => item.data.medicineType).toString());
    })
  },[])
```

Comment: Thanks! I have solved my error using your example, and the data of medicine stock has successfully passed into the React usestates.

Answer (score 0):

I'll highlight problems and solutions related to your code:

- When you try to initialize your inputs `useState`, the `medicine` array is not ready yet, since the firestore call is asynchronous, so when `medicine` array arrives, the inputs `useState` *(editMedicinName...)* initial values will be stuck to an empty array.
- You also have some problems in your data manipulation since you are placing a `type Array` inside your `editMedicine****` states, but then in your inputs `onChange` handlers you are passing strings: `setEditMedicineName(e.target.value)}`
- The solution to the first problem is to work with React hook `useEffects`.
  The first `useEffect` is executed only once on mount, it calla *firestore db*, retrieves medicines list, and sets it to your react state `medicine`.
  When `medicine` is updated, the second `useEffect` will be triggered, and inside of it you can update your input base values.
- The second problem is addressed by setting directly strings values as your input base values.
- Last but not least, I expect you don't want to show your form until you don't
  receive `medicine` data, so it's a good idea to place a *ternary
  operator* after the return, so you can show a spinner during loading
  operations.

```js
function EditMedicine() {
  const { medicineId } = useParams();

  const [medicine, setMedicine] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const q = query(
      collection(db, 'medicine'),
      where('isAccepted', '==', true)
    );
    onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
      // setMedicine is called asynchronously
      setMedicine(
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }))
      );
    });
  }, []);
  // Filter medicine array, when it will be retrieved from firestore
  const medicineStock = useMemo(
    () =>
      medicine.filter((medicineStock) => medicineStock.id === medicineId)[0]
        .data,
    [medicine]
  );

  const [editMedicineName, setEditMedicineName] = useState(null);
  const [editMedicineRegNo, setEditMedicineRegNo] = useState(null);
  const [editMedicineType, setEditMedicineType] = useState(null);

  /* Set editMedicineName, editMedicineRegNo and editMedicineType when medicine array is retrieved */

  useEffect(() => {
    if (medicine) {
      setEditMedicineName(medicineStock.medicineName);
      setEditMedicineRegNo(medicineStock.medicineRegNo);
      setEditMedicineType(medicineStock.medicinType);
    }
  }, [medicine]);

  return !medicine ? "Loading..." :(
    <div className="editMedicine">
      <div className="editMedicine-title">Edit Medicine</div>
      <form className="editMedicine-form">
        <div>
          <p>
            <label className="editMedicine-dataTitle">
              Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </label>
            <input
              name="medicineName"
              type="text"
              required
              className="editMedicine-input"
              value={editMedicineName}
              onChange={(e) => setEditMedicineName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label className="editMedicine-dataTitle">
              Reg No:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </label>
            <input
              name="medicineRegNo"
              type="text"
              required
              className="editMedicine-input"
              value={editMedicineRegNo}
              onChange={(e) => setEditMedicineRegNo(e.target.value)}
            />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label className="editMedicine-dataTitle">
              Type:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </label>
            <select
              className="editMedicine-input"
              value={editMedicineType}
              onChange={(e) => setEditMedicineType(e.target.value)}
            >
              <option value="Tablet">Tablet</option>
              <option value="Capsule">Capsule</option>
              <option value="Liquid">Liquid</option>
              <option value="Spray">Spray</option>
              <option value="Cream">Cream</option>
              <option value="Ointment">Ointment</option>
            </select>
          </p>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! I will try to implement your solutions and giving an update whether the problem is solved or not after few hours as its already midnight here.

Comment: Hi, here the update: I still can't make it work, the second useEffect where setting the `editMedicine****` will hve problem reading the `medicineStock` as the terminal returns **React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'medicineStock.medicineName','medicineStock.medicineRegNo','medicineStock.medicineType'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.** Can you help me on this issue?

Comment: That's eslint complaining you have not set all the deps. It would work even without them since `medicine` dep will hydrate medicineStock in useMemo, but if you wnt to suppress lint warn place those vaues in the array of deps. You could also replace `medicine` with `medicineStock` in the second useffect.